# How can I reduce the size of my statement for Excel to txt file and skip empty cells with no data

Tags: vba, excel

How can I reduce the size of my statement for Excel to txt file and skip empty cells with no data.  Below is a small portion of my code but is at least 204 lines long and very redundant.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Open (Cells(3, 4)) For Output As #1
   If Len(Cells(5, 6)) <> 0 Then Print #1, Replace(Cells(5, 2), "-", ""); ","; Trim(Cells(5, 6)); ","; Trim(Cells(5, 8))
   If Len(Cells(6, 6)) <> 0 Then Print #1, Replace(Cells(6, 2), "-", ""); ","; Trim(Cells(6, 6)); ","; Trim(Cells(6, 8))
If Len(Cells(7, 6)) <> 0 Then Print #1, Replace(Cells(7, 2), "-", ""); ","; Trim(Cells(7, 6)); ","; Trim(Cells(7, 8))
If Len(Cells(8, 6)) <> 0 Then Print #1, Replace(Cells(8, 2), "-", ""); ","; Trim(Cells(8, 6)); ","; Trim(Cells(8, 8))
If Len(Cells(9, 6)) <> 0 Then Print #1, Replace(Cells(9, 2), "-", ""); ","; Trim(Cells(9, 6)); ","; Trim(Cells(9, 8))
If Len(Cells(10, 6)) <> 0 Then Print #1, Replace(Cells(10, 2), "-", ""); ","; Trim(Cells(10, 6)); ","; Trim(Cells(10, 8))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could/should investigate the `For..Each` loop:

```
Dim rngGet As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set rngGet = Range(Cells(5, 6), Cells(10, 6))
'or Range("F5:F10")
For Each rng In rngGet
    'do something with rng
Next 'rng
```

[Looping through a Range MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop replacing the indices 6,7,8... by the loop variable.